# Array and Dictionary type declarations in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

According to my understanding of the documentation, this should be correct:

```
var cookies: [NSHTTPCookie] = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as [NSHTTPCookie]
```

where I'm creating an array of NSHTTPCookie objects. The interpreter does not like this syntax, however, giving me "Expected type after 'as'" and putting a little pointer at the opening bracket of the `[NSHTTPCookie]` at the end.

However, this works:

```
var cookies:NSHTTPCookie[] = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as NSHTTPCookie[]
```

From the documentation, it seems like the first version is more correct, however.

Here's another example, this time with someone else's code. No one else using this code has reported the same behavior I get. (This is just a snippet; if the context is relevant let me know and I'll post more)

```
func asDict(x: AnyObject) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    return x as? [String:AnyObject]
}
```

In this case the playground interpreter objects in both places `[String:AnyObject]` is used. It just doesn't seem to be recognizing it as a type.

I double-checked to make sure I have the most recent beta of Xcode 6, but it seems much more likely to me that the problem is in my understanding rather than in the tool, since this would be a mighty big bug for only me to experience.

Comment: That's definitely fishy if you have the newest beta. The first way is correct as of beta 3 I believe it was.

Comment: Are you on Beta 5?  As written in your post, it does look like a parsing bug.  Beta 5 did make changes to array casting, but I don't know if it would affect your problem.

Comment: Your first way works fine for me. May want to try reinstalling Xcode or maybe first try deleting your derived data. Context feels relevant now. Can you post some more relevant code?

Comment: In the end... operator error. I was using an older beta. In a way I'm glad the answer was configuration rather than misconception, but thanks all for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using an old beta, this works in Beta 5 playground:

```
import Foundation

println("hello")

var cookies:[NSHTTPCookie] = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as [NSHTTPCookie]

println("goodbye")
```

Comment: He said he double checked to make sure he has the most recent beta of Xcode 6 in his question.

Comment: @pasta And yet it is clearly a versioning issue, try my snippet above in Beta 5.  Clearly the trailing [] syntax is now deprecated.

Comment: Yes I know I've already tried it... That doesn't mean it's a versioning issue. Other people have had issues building projects in newer betas that were started in old betas. Could be something to do with that too.

Comment: If you have verified it, and the OP can verify the snippet in Beta 5, then it has to be a versioning issue - perhaps buried in the project, but a versioning issue nevertheless.  At that point though, it should be recast as a Beta 5 upgrade problem.

Comment: Well he must have launched the wrong version because your answer is accepted :)

Comment: It turns out that I was using an old beta, despite my assertion above to the contrary. Thanks for the answers and sorry to waste your time.